# Only Obfuscate & Optimize

Tags: java, kotlin, proguard

I've been messing around with Proguard config and figured out that I want to test just to optimize & obfuscate without shrinking just to reduce my jar a bit. This is my config:

```
# Include java runtime classes
-libraryjars  <java.home>/lib/rt.jar


-dontshrink
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontpreverify
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontwarn
-keep class **
-keep interface **
-keep enum **
```

But i still get errors like:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find common super class of [org/apache/logging/log4j/core/jackson/Log4jXmlModule] (with 1 known super classes) and [org/apache/logging/log4j/core/jackson/Log4jJsonModule] (with 4 known super classes)

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log4j libraries relies on some runtime dependencies, see the page here:

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/runtime-dependencies.html

The classes in question (Log4jXmlModule and Log4jJsonModule) extend from some jackson class which is only an optional dependency and thus probably not included in your project.

If you enable `-dontshrink`, ProGuard has no way to remove these classes and during optimization you get an error like that as ProGuard has no knowledge about the hierarchy. In general it is not advised to perform optimization but disable shrinking as some optimization techniques rely on the fact that shrinking cleans up afterwards.

In your case you can add the missing runtime dependency as `-libraryjar` input to ProGuard to avoid this error.